# Unable to create Apple Music user playlist within playlist folder using Java Applescript library wrapper com.tagtraum.obstmusic

Tags: java, applescript

Trying to use https://github.com/japlscript/obstmusic to talk to Apple Music app on Macos with Java, I used to write native applescript and then java applescript library but that was removed from Java.

In this case I cant work out to create a user playlist within a folder playlist, when I run the code

```
    public void createPlaylist() throws Exception
    {
        FolderPlaylist songkongPlaylistFolder = getPlayListFolder();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm");
        String playlistname = "SongKong:" + sdf.format(new Date());
        Application app = Application.getInstance();

        Map<String, Reference> properties = new HashMap<>();
        Object userPlaylist = app.make(TypeClass.fromClass(UserPlaylist.class), songkongPlaylistFolder, properties);
        ((UserPlaylist)userPlaylist).setName(playlistname);
    }
```

I get exception

> 04/04/2022
> 14.52.44:BST:OSXUpdateItunesWithChanges:updateItunes:SEVERE: *** Unable to run itunes update:{     NSAppleScriptErrorAppName = Music;
> NSAppleScriptErrorBriefMessage = "Can’t make some data into the
> expected type.";     NSAppleScriptErrorMessage = "Music got an error:
> Can’t make some data into the expected type.";
> NSAppleScriptErrorNumber = "-1700";     NSAppleScriptErrorRange =
> "NSRange: {23, 93}"; }
> com.tagtraum.japlscript.execution.JaplScriptException: {
> NSAppleScriptErrorAppName = Music;     NSAppleScriptErrorBriefMessage
> = "Can’t make some data into the expected type.";     NSAppleScriptErrorMessage = "Music got an error: Can’t make some data
> into the expected type.";     NSAppleScriptErrorNumber = "-1700";
> NSAppleScriptErrorRange = "NSRange: {23, 93}"; }  at
> com.tagtraum.japlscript.execution.CocoaScriptExecutor.execute(Native
> Method)   at
> com.tagtraum.japlscript.execution.CocoaScriptExecutor.executeImpl(CocoaScriptExecutor.java:28)
> at
> com.tagtraum.japlscript.execution.ScriptExecutor.execute(ScriptExecutor.java:102)
> at
> com.tagtraum.japlscript.ObjectInvocationHandler.executeAppleScript(ObjectInvocationHandler.java:476)
> at
> com.tagtraum.japlscript.ObjectInvocationHandler.executeAppleScript(ObjectInvocationHandler.java:468)
> at
> com.tagtraum.japlscript.ObjectInvocationHandler.executeAppleScript(ObjectInvocationHandler.java:464)
> at
> com.tagtraum.japlscript.ObjectInvocationHandler.invokeCommand(ObjectInvocationHandler.java:280)
> at
> com.tagtraum.japlscript.ObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(ObjectInvocationHandler.java:191)
> at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy59.make(Unknown Source)  at
> com.jthink.songkong.ituneshelper.OSXUpdateMusicWithChanges.createPlaylist(OSXUpdateMusicWithChanges.java:62)
> at
> com.jthink.songkong.ituneshelper.OSXUpdateItunesWithChanges.analyseFiles(OSXUpdateItunesWithChanges.java:246)
> at
> com.jthink.songkong.ituneshelper.OSXUpdateItunesWithChanges.updateItunes(OSXUpdateItunesWithChanges.java:126)
> at
> com.jthink.songkong.ituneshelper.UpdateItunesWithChanges.call(UpdateItunesWithChanges.java:184)
> at
> com.jthink.songkong.ituneshelper.UpdateItunesWithChanges.call(UpdateItunesWithChanges.java:33)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)

I think the problem is how I call `app.make()` but I cant work out how to do it.

Comment: Tipp: Oftentimes it is useful to crank up the logging for *JaplScript* to see the generated AppleScript snippets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it buried quite away down in the README.md file of the base project https://github.com/japlscript/japlscript

```
Reference reference = app.make(UserPlaylist.CLASS, songkongPlaylistFolder, null);
UserPlaylist userPlaylist = reference.cast(UserPlaylist.class);
userPlaylist.setName(playlistname);
```